# Cannot get heading data (for compass app) in swift2 on ios9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, compass

Trying to get the basics of a simple compass app working in swift 2, using xcode 7 and testing in the ios simulator.

I cannot seem to get the heading information.

My app currently prints GeoLocation data just fine, but does not print heading data.

Contents of ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{


var lm = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    lm.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    lm.delegate = self
    lm.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    lm.startUpdatingHeading()
    lm.startUpdatingLocation()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    print(newHeading)
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    print(locations)
}
}
```

I have also added this to my Info.plist file as well as adding CoreLocation to my liked libraries.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Lemmie have your location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Gimmie</string>
```

Sample Console output looks like this:

> [<+37.33761534,-122.03479147> +/- 5.00m (speed 5.75 mps / course
>   271.71) @ 4/26/16, 1:31:07 AM British Summer Time]
>
> [<+37.33761751,-122.03485278> +/- 5.00m (speed 5.32 mps / course
>   272.27) @ 4/26/16, 1:31:08 AM British Summer Time]
>
> [<+37.33762005,-122.03491577> +/- 5.00m (speed 5.50 mps / course
>   272.11) @ 4/26/16, 1:31:09 AM British Summer Time]
>
> [<+37.33762244,-122.03497889> +/- 5.00m (speed 5.52 mps / course
>   271.42) @ 4/26/16, 1:31:10 AM British Summer Time]
>
> [<+37.33762300,-122.03504341> +/- 5.00m (speed 5.52 mps / course
>   270.29) @ 4/26/16, 1:31:11 AM British Summer Time] ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is heading information available while running in the simulator.  I tested your code and it works fine on my iPhone 6.